# Show only latest updated nodes

Tags: views

I'm getting data from a source. In the following example, there is no data in drupal database and there are 4 source "nodes" that I will import. The content type is set to create revisions.

So, **first time** I import data this is what I get:

[image]

The update date is `22/11/2015 12:00` for all 4 nodes and views has to show them all.

After half an hour, I make another import from the same source but, data 2 was deleted, so, It will not be imported.

I get this:

[image]

At drupal db (green block), you can see that the update date was not changed, only the other 3 nodes were changed.

Is some way (that I don't know how), I need my view to show only nodes 1, 3 and 4, basically, the latest that were updated.

Important to note that, no matter how many nodes I import, the update date will always be the same.
Also, I can add fields to my content type and set values when the nodes are first imported or updated and try to use that as filters.

How can I implement this with views? Or, if not possible with views, any other suggestion?

Comment: I think "only nodes 1, 2 and 3" contains a typo, and should probably be "only nodes 1, 3 and 4" ... Also in your first line you should add "to start with", because after import there WILL be data in your DB, no?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal views support sorting with timestamps by default. You need to install the Date module to add support for date sorting in views. I also recommend that you import the data from your source with the feeds module and use another date field for your date NOT the property "updated" which is a timestamp.

Another solution is to convert the date from your source to timestamp as you import it. The tamper add on module for feeds may help you do this.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, but that doesn't solve it. Sorting by date, whatever date is, will always show data 2. I think I have to create another display, sort it by update date (latest), show only 1 result and the use that value as filter in my display.

Comment: make sure that the field you re checking actually contains a date in a valid format. The easiest way to do this is to enable the devel module and do something like dpm(node_load($nid_of_the_node_you_want_to_check)); from the devel php screen

Comment: Maybe the best solution is to create a Custom Filter Handler that gives me the most recent update date value of all the nodes? Can someone teach me how can I do this? I already created the handler but not the code to get the value.